# Why the mean value from NCO::ncra is defferent from terra::tapp()?

Tags: r, raster, netcdf, terra, nco

I have a .nc file containing daily data for a whole year, and I tried to calculate the mean value for each month.

I tried to us Linux command `ncra` provided by [netCDF Operator (NCO)](https://nco.sourceforge.net/).
The result seems nothing wrong, as the time stamp of the output file is the middle date of each month.
However, when I use `terra::tapp(daily_nc, indices2, fun = mean)` to double check my result, it seems `ncra` get a different mean value

| NCO::ncra | terra::tapp |
| --- | --- |
| 251.8105 | 251.9165 |

Here is the complete code I used:

```
# load pacakges
require(pacman)
pacman::p_load(dplyr, tidyverse, terra, RColorBrewer, scales)

wd <- '~/RA/CMIP6/'

base <- 'https://nex-gddp-cmip6.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/NEX-GDDP-CMIP6'
mdl <- 'ACCESS-CM2'
prd <- 'historical'
var <- 'tasmax'

# download data
urli <- paste0(base, '/', mdl, '/', prd, '/', 'r1i1p1f1', '/', var, '/', var, '_day_', mdl, '_', prd, '_', 'r1i1p1f1', '_gn_2000.nc')
setwd(wd)
system(paste0("axel -a -n 5 ", urli))
file.name <- paste0(var, '_day_', mdl, '_', prd, '_', 'r1i1p1f1', '_gn_2000.nc')

# ---------- ncra ----------------

# initial date for month
days_start <- seq(as.Date(paste0("2000-01-01")), length = 12, by = "months")
days_end <- seq(as.Date(paste0("2000-02-01")), length = 12, by = "months") - 1

# monthly mean
for(m in 1:12){
  system(paste0('ncra -O -d time,"', days_start[m], '","', days_end[m], '" ', wd, file.name, ' ', wd, 'monthly_', m, '.nc'))
}
# stack monthly mean in one .nc file
system(paste0('ncrcat ', wd, 'monthly_*.nc ', wd, gsub('day', 'month' , file.name)))

# delete intermediate files
system(paste0('rm ', wd, 'monthly_*.nc'))

r_nco <- rast(paste0(wd, gsub('day', 'month' , file.name)))

# ------------ terra::tapp -----------------

r <- rast(paste0(wd, file.name))
indices <- format(time(r), format = "%m") %>%
  as.double()
r_terra <- tapp(r, indices, fun = mean)
time(r_terra) <- seq(as.Date(paste0("2000-01-15")), length = 12, by = "months")

# ---------- plot and compare --------------
col <- brewer_pal(palette = "RdYlBu", direction = -1)(5)
plot(r_nco, col = col)
plot(r_terra, col = col)

# find a pixel with value in 2000.01
time(r_nco)
r_nco[[1]][90490]
time(r_terra)
r_terra[[1]][90490]
```

[The plot of NCO result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIIZE.png)

[The plot of terra result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xkyz.png)

Comment: Without access to the data it is hard to answer definitively. But my suspicion is that this could be a numerical precision issue. I believe NCO uses the precision defined in the Netcdf files, but terra converts to float. So if the raw files have integer format I’d expect the two methods to give slightly different results

Comment: You do not show sufficient code and data. How was `indices2` created? And what does `terra::tapp(daily_nc, "month", fun = mean)` return?  Is the difference similar for all months? It seems reasonable to assume that you made a coding error.

Comment: @RobertWilson Thank you for that! However, my original data is CMIP6 NetCDF file downloaded from NASA, the format is Float32, and both terra and NCO output file is FLoat32, too. (I checked format by gdalinfo)

Comment: @RobertHijmans Sorry for insufficient info. `indices2` was created by `r <- rast(file.path); indices <- format(time(r), format = "%m") %>% as.double()`, so `terra::tapp(daily_nc, "month", fun = mean)` return a NetCDF file contains monthly value with 12 layers. It seemes no error in terra code as the ploting results are reasonable.

Comment: Thanks, but please edit your question, instead of commenting. Also, can you please include the result of `show(r)`

Comment: You will need to make this reproducible. This is either a coding or a data issue, but without seeing either of them it’s difficult to give further advice

Comment: @RobertWilson Thank you for advice, I have updated reproducible code in my question.

Comment: @RobertHijmans Yes I have updated plot results in question, and thanks for editing question!

Comment: You are not showing any data. How do you expect us to help you? Include, at minimum, what is returned by  `show(r)`,  `head(time(r))` and `tapp(r, "months", fun = mean)`; and the difference between that output and `r_terra` and the result obtained with nco.

Answer (score 0):

NCO behaves almost as @Robert Wilson comments above. Unless told otherwise, NCO converts the on-disk type to double-precision, does the arithmetic, then converts back to the input/output type. This could explain the discrepancy if the `terra::tapp` method treats the data differently.

Comment: Thank you! but I also convert rast read by terra to double-precision when checking my result, i'm still confused for the dircrepancy.